# Excel macro exporting pdf as one column one page, wheter I need to export enitre sheet on page

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I have dynamically updating excel file.
I'm trying to export excel file as pdf, using excel macro. It saves excel column as one page. But I need to save active sheet as a page.
Here my VBA code:

```
Sub SaveActiveSheetsAsPDF(Path As String)

'Create and assign variables
Dim saveLocation As String
saveLocation = Path

With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
End With


'Save Active Sheet(s) as PDF
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=saveLocation
    

End Sub
```

I've tried to set range .PrintArea = "$A$1:$F$(number)", but it doesn't work.

Comment: Assuming that `number` holds the last row you want to print, try `.PrintArea = "$A$1:$F$" & number`

Comment: @FunThomas I've tried to set static range like .PrintArea = "$A$1:$F$500", but nothing changed